# Chrome Dev Tools Mac - console log messages not showing

Tags: macos, google-chrome-devtools

I am running the current version of Chrome for Mac.  I cannot get the console messages to display. It says there are 4 user messages but I actually want to view them, and I cannot.

Quite how a major vendor could release a critical product and make it so difficult to use is beyond me.

I did manage to view the messages yesterday, but that was a fluke and I don't know how I did it.

I have read ALL the answers for this issue (clearly this is not an isolated problem) but none of those answers either apply or work.

If anyone knows how to display the console log messages on a Mac I would really appreciate a response.

Comment: Close the filtering mini-panel on the left of the console panel. Also clear any text in the filter input in the console's toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I closed Chrome Dev Tools and restarted it - it worked and I get my console messages now.  No idea why I had to do that...